# How to create nested component form

Tags: forms, angular, typescript

I am developing web app with Angular 4, but I try create a form but I can't create correctly this, I can't bind my data from my child components.

This is my directory files, when the important folders are `dashboard`, `filter-time` (`filter` and `selection`), they are my principal components to create my form.

```
src/app/
├── app-routing.module.ts
├── app.component.css
├── app.component.html
├── app.component.ts
├── app.module.ts
├── dashboard
│   ├── dashboard.component.css
│   ├── dashboard.component.html
│   └── dashboard.component.ts
├── filter-time
│   ├── filter
│   │   ├── filter.component.css
│   │   ├── filter.component.html
│   │   └── filter.component.ts
│   ├── filter-time.component.css
│   ├── filter-time.component.html
│   ├── filter-time.component.ts
│   └── selection
│       ├── selection.component.css
│       ├── selection.component.html
│       └── selection.component.ts
└── shared
    ├── dashboard.service.ts
    ├── data-table.service.ts
    ├── data-table.ts
    ├── selection-data.ts
    └── selection.service.ts
```

I add an image to explain the real distribution of my form logic.

[Form view final](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mig2X.png)

- Blue : `dashboard` component, this html file contains a form with my filter-time component and button `Buscar`.
- Green: `filter-time` Component, this contains a `filter` and `selection` component.
- Red: Contain two `md-datepicker` components.
- Orange: Contain only four `md-select` components.

I add my form definition from dashboard.component.html

```
<form #f="ngForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit(f)" novalidate>
      <md-card>
        <div
          class="container"
          fxLayout
          fxLayout.xs="column"
          fxLayoutAlign="center"
          fxLayoutGap="10px"
          fxLayoutGap.xs="0">
          <div class="item item-1" fxFlex="90%" fxFlexOrder="1">
            <app-filter-time>Loading filter time...</app-filter-time>
          </div>
          <div class="item item-2" fxFlex="10%" fxFlexOrder="2">
            <button md-raised-button>Buscar</button>
          </div>
        </div>
      </md-card>
</form>
```

filter-time.component.html definition

```
<div
  class="container"
  fxLayout
  fxLayout.xs="row"
  fxLayoutAlign="center"
  fxLayoutGap="10px"
  fxLayoutGap.xs="0">
  <div class="item item-1" fxFlex="20%" fxFlexOrder="1">
    <app-filter type_d="Fecha de inicio" [value]=defaultDateStart></app-filter>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-2" fxFlex="23%" fxFlexOrder="2">
    <app-filter type_d="Fecha de termino" [value]=defaultDateEnd></app-filter>
  </div>
  <div class="item item-3" fxFlex="62%" fxFlexOrder="3">
    <app-selection></app-selection>
  </div>
</div>
```

And I add filter.component.html because is the ultimate nested component and same selection.component, but I think that logic is same for two nested components, but I'll add this just in case you want to see it.

```
<md-input-container>
  <input
    mdInput
    [mdDatepicker]="picker"
    [placeholder]=[type_d]
    [min]="minDate"
    [max]="maxDate"
    [value]=date
    [(ngModel)]=fecha
    ngModel
    required>
  <button mdSuffix [mdDatepickerToggle]="picker"></button>
</md-input-container>
<md-datepicker #picker></md-datepicker>
```

When I press the button in my terminal I can't see my data, but in my `onSubmit` method I try `console.log(f.value)`.

dashboard.component.ts (onSubmit in specific)

```
onSubmit(f: NgForm) {
    console.log("Form values -> ", f.value);
}
```

Comment: Where are your classes? Do they implement the ControlValueAccessor?

Comment: What classes do you need to see? But I have not implemented any of that

Comment: For your subcontrols, like the filter-time component. That would explain why it's not working; you need to implement that interface, and also connect it to the right value in the dashboard template. As it stands it's not clear why you thought this *would* work.

Comment: I don't understand what I need implement, I can filter-time.component.ts, but I don't know what to do, please guide me.

Comment: Guidance is too broad for SO, it's not a tutorial service. I'd suggest you do more research on writing your own form controls; search for the interface I mention above, for example.

Comment: Okay, But I have ultimate question for my files, Can I have filter with same picker like filter-time, for #picker is my question.

Comment: I don't understand what you're trying to ask. Do the research, then [edit] if you still have a question.

Comment: @fm433403 You seem do be doing quite a lot of things without having much idea about where it is going wrong. Just to begin with, start with something very small and work your way from there. I really want to help, but it is hard to understand from here. Perhaps a plunkr to start with?

Comment: @ThomasSebastian But plunkr asks me to put all the dependencies of my project

Comment: Won't it be possible to just recreate the form component? The one you posted an image of? If it's too much, then fine; You don't have to.